# E: Unable to locate package libboost / libxerces E: Package 'libzeroc-ice-java' has no installation candidate

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, package-management, error-handling

I am trying to install `RebeccaAIML` dependecies as it says here: https://github.com/codeanticode/chatbots-library/wiki/Linux-installation-of-RebeccaAIML , by this command:

```
apt-get install libboost libxerces libzeroc-ice-java
```

But I got these error messages:

```
E: Unable to locate package libboost
E: Unable to locate package libxerces
E: Package 'libzeroc-ice-java' has no installation candidate
```

I tried to add this repo but didn't work:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Comment: `RebeccaAIML` , RebeccaAIML-src-981/ : The time stamps say 2005, 2006. .......  "libboost" : The current -devel package name is `libboost-all-dev` . "libxerces" : Probably `libxerces-c2-dev` . "libzeroc-ice-java" : 10 year old package, `libzeroc-ice3.3-java_3.3.1-12_all.deb` http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/pool/main/z/zeroc-ice/ . ( Old xerces-c v.2.6 , old boost may work . Compiler to use: gcc/g++ version 3.4.6 , I guess.)